# Set selectedValue of combobox bind to datasource

Tags: c#, combobox

I've a combobox, set to a datasource of an array set into dictionary. I was able to get back the selected value using combobox.SelectedValue and cast it to the object. but how do i set it back to the selectedValue for the combobox when i want to display the information again on 'edit mode' of the form?

```
  BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
  bindingSource.DataSource = array.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a);
  comboBox.DataSource = bindingSource
  comboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
  comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

i tried to do the following and could not set it back

```
 public void SetComboBox(ClassA a)
 {
   comboBox.SelectedValue = a;
 }
```

Comment: Use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue. It will only work if the Equals method is true when comparing the combobox items and the object you are trying to set. So if you are not using the same object reference, you might want to override Equals on your class.

Comment: Ive did a keyvaluepair and tried to use selectedItem still to no avail, any idea why?

Comment: No, I don't really know . Why are you converting to dictionary anyway?

Comment: well, i need the combobox to return an object instead of a property of the object.

Comment: Class A is an object, and arrays are enumerable so you can bind to them.